# @Before Advice Annotation not Applied in the Spring Application

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have been trying to develop a small application that demonstrates the @Before Annotation , but its not working

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>aopdemo</groupId>
<artifactId>aopdemo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

AccoutDAO.java file is

```
   package org.java.aop.dao;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class AccoutDAO {
    public void addAccount()
    {
        System.out.println("Adding account"+getClass());
    }
}
```

The Aspect configuration file is

```
   package org.java.aop.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspects {

    @Before("execution(public void addAccount())")
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("=====================>>CALLING Aspects");
    }
}
```

The spring config file(spring-config.xml) is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
<bean id="accountDAO" class="org.java.aop.dao.AccoutDAO">
</bean>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

</beans>
```

And finally my main code is

```
    package org.java.aop;
import org.java.aop.dao.AccoutDAO;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class MainDemo {

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        try
        {
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
            AccoutDAO accoutDAO=context.getBean("accountDAO",AccoutDAO.class);
            accoutDAO.addAccount();
            context.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get the output as "INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-config.xml]
Adding accountclass org.java.aop.dao.AccoutDAO
Nov 22, 2018 2:06:14 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1ed6993a: startup date [Thu Nov 22 02:06:14 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy"

But i could not able to get the output for @Before Annotation.Kindly tell me whats wrong in this code

Answer (score 0):

The above problem is resolved by adding component scan in spring-config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
<bean id="accountDAO" class="org.java.aop.dao.AccoutDAO">
</bean>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.java.aop"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Still you should fix your dependency management. You have a very old version of _aspectjrt_ versus a relatively new one of _aspectjweaver_. Furthermore, _aspectjweaver_ is a superset of _aspectjrt_, so you do not need the runtime at all. And according to the [Maven dependencies of _spring-aop_](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.0.6.RELEASE) even _aspectjweaver_ is an optional dependency. Try if it works without both, but definitely you should get rid of _aspectjrt_ including the version mismatch.